# Function to explicitly istantiate a given template function with more standard types?

Tags: c++, templates, header, c++17

I have the following question. Supposing I have a header file `header.hpp` with this template function declaration:

```
template <typename T> extern T func();
```

And in the `header.cpp` file I have the function definition:

```
template <typename T> T func() { \* do something */ };

//Following lines are for explicit istantiation of the template for some types:
template double func <double> (); //1
template int func <int>(); //2
//And others...
```

Does exists a function / class or something else which allows me to explicitly istantiate a template class definition for more templated types without the needing of writing something like lines 1 or 2 of the previous code everytime?

I am searching for something like, for example:

```
void function ( template_function list_of_types )
 {
  //explicit istantiations of the template_function for the types given in the list_of_types container...
 }
```

The signature doesn't have to be as the one above, but also similar, the important thing is that it works as I said before. Thanks.

Comment: From your pseudo syntax, you might be able to implicitly instantiate the function, but not explicitly (so it would be useless).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no function like that. The explicit template instantiation must appear at namespace scope, so a "function" like that would have to be some sort of compiler magic (that doesn't exist), or use the preprocessor to expand into the required declarations.

Something like [Boost.PP](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) has machinery to approximate what you are after. As an example:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp>

#define ARGS(...) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__))

template <typename T> void func(T) { };
#define EXPANSION(r, data, elem) template void func<elem>(elem);

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(EXPANSION, _, ARGS(int,double,char))
```

[See the preprcoessor output live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:59,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:59,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:59,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:59,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Cboost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp%3E%0A%23include+%3Cboost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp%3E%0A%0A%23define+ARGS(...)+BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__))%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E+void+func(T)+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%23define+EXPANSION(r,+data,+elem)+template+void+func%3Celem%3E(elem)%3B%0A%0ABOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(EXPANSION,+_,+ARGS(int,double,char))%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27178%27)),options:%27-E%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

It may irritate those with a preprocessor allergy, but it is one of the few legitimate uses for preprocessing remaining. At least until the C++ standard's committee chooses to give us better tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if instead I have two template parameters? How should I handle with the last line of your code?

Answer (score -1):

You could use concepts (or requires) and create specialized versions of your template.

So if you have

```
void func(auto t) { ...}
```

you could define a concept "AllowedNumericalTypes" and write another template like

```
void func(AllowedNumericalTypes auto t) { /*1 and 2 */ }
```

The compiler will choose the most matching version of your func methods and then call those.

```
btw. template<typename T> void func(T t)
 is identical to 
void func(auto t)
```